# Media Player stopped working

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming, sony-xperia

In some devices. Its working fine but specially Sony it stuck with this error
please help, thanks in advance

**MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
                 ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails**

Comment: I guess I'm having the same problem. My alarm clock sporadically doesn't play any sound and sometimes the sound stopped after about 3 seconds. In the log I can see the same error messages. I tried to use the Sony support chat and getting some standard answers: Restart your phone, do a factory reset, ... Now I've wrote a mail. It seems to be a bug in their software.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: The problem seems to be disappeared after removing RingDimmer. Do you have RingDimmer installed?

Comment: No I don't have

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - MediaPlayer was not working and logging the error you mentioned on a Sony Android device.Then I realized that the MediaPlayer was working all along. It's just that device "Media volume" was set to zero.

My suggestion - ignore the logged error and try to find the issue elsewhere.